Laravel unable to save model instance to the DB
I have a simple model Ranks which has 2 string attributes - fullName and shortName (also id as primary key and the timestamps). But then I try to save the data to DB it seems like my attributes with data are ignored and the Laravel prepares the MySQL request without them. As a result I'm getting the error regarding missing fullName which can't be empty. (General error: 1364 Field 'fullName' doesn't have a default value) It's a really simple taks that I've been stuck on for several hours what am I doing wrong?
In Ranks Controller:
$rank = new Rank();
$rank->fullName = 'Hello';
$rank->shortName = 'World';
$rank->save();

The error I'm getting:

My Model Rank:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Rank extends Model
{
    public $fullName;
    public $shortName;
}

And a I've used this migration to create the DB table:
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('ranks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('fullName')->unique()->nullable(false);
            $table->string('shortName')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('ranks');
    }
};

My table structure looks like this


class Rank extends Model { public $fullName; public $shortName; } <- That's actually your issue there. You're defining public properties from your column names, which due to Laravel magic, makes them null when you're calling $rank->save(). If you simply define your model as class Rank extends Model { }, your code should actually work fine.

No problem! I've run into that same issue a few times, but it's due to how Laravel "automagically" maps your columns to properties, like $rank->full_name, etc. I haven't dug into why, that's beyond my scope of knowledge, and it makes it a little annoying for type-hinting/intellisense/etc. but ‍♂️

Please do not post images of code/data/errors - edit your question and copy-paste the text of your MySQL error.

You have not defined your model class correctly.  By creating public class variables matching your table schema, you are interfering with the way Laravel Eloquent is designed to work, which makes use of PHP magic getter/setters.
If you take a look at the Laravel Model class, you can see how this behavior was accomplished.  This blog post is old, but goes into some detail in regards to how Eloquent Models work.
Keep in mind that Laravel is maintaining fetched value/updated values in support of its "active record" implementation, so it needs to maintain the state of the mapped objects (Model objects).  It manages the model data for you, and you only need to add things to the model class when mapping conventions conflict with the naming of attributes
You should:

remove the fullname and shortname class variables from Rank.
(Optionally) you can add a protected $fillable array that acts like a whitelist for attributes you will allow to be manually updated, as per your code.

    /**
      * The attributes that are mass assignable.
      *
      * @var array
      */
      protected $fillable = ['fullName', 'shortName'];

By providing the attribute list in fillable you can then use Model::create() as an alternative to instantiating an object, setting attributes individually, and calling save.
$rank = Rank::create([
    'fullName' => 'Hello', 
    'shortName' => 'World'
]);

I would highly advise that you read through the Eloquent manual, as it covers these concepts as well as the availability of Accessors, Mutators and Attribute Casting, all of which might have utility for you in the future.

Another alternative to $fillable but is $guarded  which allows mass assignment. Read more here https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#allowing-mass-assignment

fillable is only for mass assignment and the OP is not assigning via mass assignment

@lagbox: fillable or guarded is not only for mass assignment.  It enables the use of the Model::create(), which is one of the reasons I brought it up.

yea that is all mass assignment, if you can pass attributes in "mass" it is mass assignment, which these methods use fill to set the attributes hence "fillable"
